# Understanding the $\phi^4$ -interaction

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, interactions

Im having problems understanding the $\phi^4$ self-interaction intuitively.
Firstly, I hope I understand the interaction itself correctly.
It consists of *two incoming* particles and *two outgoing* particles, interacting through a point-like vertex.

Secondly, if the lagrangian density is given by 
\begin{equation}
 -\frac{\lambda}{4!}\left|{\phi}\right|^2
\end{equation}
The Feynman diagram yields
[image]

My question is, what happens to the factor of $4!$? [here](https://www.physics.uu.se/digitalAssets/405/c_405910-l_1-k_qft.pdf) i found an explanation:

> the factor of $4!$ does not appear in (3.2.13) because we are assuming that there are four other fields that will attach to the vertex and there are 4! ways for choosing how these four fields pair up with the four fields that make up the vertex.

How do four other fields attach to the vertex? Do they mean that there are $4!$ ways the fields can attach to the vertex? (If this is true, the diagram actually represents $4!$ diffrent diagrams?) And in the case of a complex scalar field, shouldn't the factor change due to charge conservation?

Comment: Yes, there are 4! combinations for four external fields to pair with the four fields of the vertex. Yes in a sense you can think of that diagram as representing 4! different pairings. Yes having a complex field changes the combinatorics.

Comment: thank you @octonion ! So for the complex scalar case, the vertex can both represent scattering ($\phi \phi\rightarrow \phi \phi$, $\phi^* \phi^*\rightarrow \phi^* \phi^*$ as well as annihilation ($\phi \phi^*\rightarrow \phi \phi^*$)?

Comment: Yes, although the interpretation in terms of which scattering process depends on the external legs in the diagram (the S-matrix and all that). Your original question was in principle somewhat different since it applies to off-shell diagrams and simply pairing fields.